# Following a tutorial: cannot run Docker container of Django

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

I am following [this tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application) to create Django API and run it on docker.
The API runs well without docker, however I have issues with running it on docker.

The tutorial says that Dockerfile should be created:

```
# Dockerfile

# FROM directive instructing base image to build upon
FROM python:2-onbuild

# COPY startup script into known file location in container
COPY start.sh /start.sh

# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000

# CMD specifcies the command to execute to start the server running.
CMD ["/start.sh"]
# done!
```

Then a docker container should be built:

```
docker build -t davidsale/dockerizing-python-django-app .
```

Until now everything is ok. But the last command fails:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 davidsale/djangoapp1
```

Error:

```
Starting Gunicorn.
[2018-11-01 19:24:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2018-11-01 19:24:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2018-11-01 19:24:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-11-01 19:24:16 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2018-11-01 19:24:16 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld.wsgi'
[2018-11-01 19:24:16 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[2018-11-01 19:24:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-11-01 19:24:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Just to mention that I have the following organisation of folders:

```
helloworld
  - helloworld
       - __init__.py
       - wsgi.py
       - settings.py
       - urls.py
       - views.py
  - dbsqlite3
  - manage.py
Dockerfile
requirements.txt
start.sh
```

Comment: That tutorial appears to be somewhat broken. Take a look at the comments, particularly the ones from harrycaveman. (The `Dockerfile` you show here appears to be missing some key pieces: you need to `COPY` your code to your container, and it's likely that you need to set the `WORKDIR` as well. There may be more issues.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your project directory to your docker image. The tutorial you are following had a mistake in dockerfile content and hadn't any `WORKDIR` variable in it:

```
# Dockerfile

# FROM directive instructing base image to build upon
FROM python:2-onbuild

# COPY startup script into known file location in container
COPY start.sh /start.sh

# Sets workdir
WORKDIR helloworld


# EXPOSE port 8000 to allow communication to/from server
EXPOSE 8000


# CMD specifcies the command to execute to start the server running.
CMD ["/start.sh"]
# done!
```